# requestAnimationFrame passing an argument to the function it is passed somehow?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript from eloquent javascript and encountered the following code:

```
<p style="text-align: center">
  <img src="img/cat.png" style="position: relative">
</p>
<script>
  var cat = document.querySelector("img");
  var angle = 0, lastTime = null;
  function animate(time) {
    if (lastTime != null)
      angle += (time - lastTime) * 0.001;
    lastTime = time;
    cat.style.top = (Math.sin(angle) * 20) + "px";
    cat.style.left = (Math.cos(angle) * 200) + "px";
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
</script>
```

from http://eloquentjavascript.net/13_dom.html
I don't understand though how the time value gets its value the first time animate is called. It seems as though requestAnimationFrame is passing the time argument to animate, but how does it know to do that, where does it get the argument from>

Answer (score 0):

> The callback method is passed a single argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time when callbacks queued by requestAnimationFrame begin to fire

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

animation in the callback function which the browser calls each time it repaints/refreshes the page.

typically the function requestAnimationFrame is called according to the refresh rate of the monitor (60fps for example). So each time it calls the callback function to repaint the canvas, it sets the current time.

Imagine the code for requestAnimationFrame to be something like this in the underlying framework

```
 window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
          timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };
```

http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/ gives a clear explanation about the function and the framework.